# What is the difference between truncate and cascade?

Tags: database

I'd like to know the exact difference between truncate and cascade in SQL.

Comment: No upvote and neither did you chose any of the below answers...?

Comment: @verisimilitude, give him a break, he's new to SO and it's his first question. Besides, he hasn't been online for the past 5 hours...

Answer (score 1):

**Cascading referential integrity** constraints allow you to define the actions which should occur when a user attempts to delete or update a key to which an existing foreign keys point.

Commonly observed actions

1. No Action: This is the default behaviour. No Action specifies that if an attempt is made to delete or update a row with a key referenced by foreign keys in existing rows in other tables, an error is raised and the DELETE or UPDATE is rolled back.
2. Cascade: Specifies that if an attempt is made to delete or update a row with a key referenced by foreign keys in existing rows in other tables, all rows containing those foreign keys are also deleted or updated.
3. Set NULL: Specifies that if an attempt is made to delete or update a row with a key referenced by foreign keys in existing rows in other tables, all rows containing those foreign keys are set to NULL.
4. Set Default: Specifies that if an attempt is made to delete or update a row with a key referenced by foreign keys in existing rows in other tables, all rows containing those foreign keys are set to default values.

**Truncate::** 
TRUNCATE normally deletes off all rows from a table and unlike a DELETE it cannot be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

Could you ellaborate?

Truncate is logically equivalent to `DELETE FROM Table;` in the sense that it removes every existing tuple in the given table. It's different because it bypasses several integrity checks (dependent on the DB flavor I believe). It also cannot be rolled back.

If you are sure you want to eliminate every item in the table, `TRUNCATE` also has the advantage of resetting any `auto increment` values on columns, with `delete from Table` will leave gaps in your auto incremented values.

Cascade allows you to define the behavior of an operation that updates or deletes a tuple in a way that would affect referential integrity (usually a foreign key).

Answer (score 1):

`TRUNCATE` basically means 'empty'. For instance you can truncate your colon when you´re going to the toilet. Use this if you want to maintain your table but get rid of all the data in it.

`TRUNCATE TABLE students` -> remove all the data in the STUDENTS table.

This can be handy for test databases for example.

`CASCADE` is used when deleting a record or table and basically means 'and everything attached to it'. This can be tricky to use. For instance if you would DELETE your PC, you would still have your 3 monitors, mouse, keyboard and your awesome sound system. However if you would CASCADE DELETE your PC, you will lose everything attached to the pc as well. Leaving you with only your desk and your chair.

`CASCADE DELETE FROM STUDENTS WHERE name = 'John'` -> Remove all the 'John's from the STUDENTS table, along with data in any other table that belongs to 'John'.

Be sure to know what will be deleted when CASCADE DELETEing something.